# C# Incremental Source Generator caching bug?

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I'm trying to wrap my head around the new Roslyn Incremental Source Generators, by making a simple generator, that lists all invoked methods in a file called InvokedMethods.g.cs.

It **almost** works, but there is an issue when typing in Visual Studio. Or more specfically, when deleting the last method invocation, because then the source generator doesn't produce an empty file, as I would expect it to do.

Either I don't fully understand the way CreateSyntaxProvider is supposed to work (which is quite likely) otherwise there is a bug in the Visual Studio 2022 implementation?

```
[Generator]
public class ListMethodInvocationsGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        IncrementalValueProvider<ImmutableArray<string>> invokedMethodsProvider = context.SyntaxProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider(
                predicate: (node, _) => node is InvocationExpressionSyntax,
                transform: (ctx, _) => (ctx.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(ctx.Node).Symbol)?.Name ?? "<< method not found >>")
            .Collect();

        context.RegisterSourceOutput(invokedMethodsProvider, (SourceProductionContext spc, ImmutableArray<string> invokedMethods) =>
        {
            var src = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var method in invokedMethods)
            {
                src.AppendLine("// " + method);
            }
            spc.AddSource("InvokedMethods.g.cs", src.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-source-generator-part-1-creating-an-incremental-source-generator/)

Comment: @McNets thanks! That was actually the turorial I was following, but the examples always combines compilation with 'context.CompilationProvider.Combine', which makes the generator run more frequently and perhaps "works correctly" by accident. I'm not at all sure about this claim, but it just seems that way to me...

Comment: What actually happens when you delete the last invocation?  The file still contains the deleted invocation?   Also, beware that `context.CompilationProvider.Combine` is [utterly anathema](https://twitter.com/kirkwoll/status/1526345483857211395) to incremental source generrator performance.  I got a ton of mileage out of this excellenty series by Pawel Gerr here:  https://www.thinktecture.com/en/net/roslyn-source-generators-performance/

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks for confirming my suspicion, that CompilationProvider.Combine can ruin the whole point of an incremental generator. The tutorial from Pawel Gerr seems really good! (Just skimmed over it right now) Yes, when deleting the last invocation, the file InvokedMethods.g.cs still contains one or more (cached?) invocations. It seems a bit "random" to me... can't make sense of it.

Comment: I just tried to replicate your example and both through Dependencies->Analyzers within the IDE, and through generated files there is a empty file. 

I'm using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp v4.20 and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers 3.3.3. 
As I understand it the predicate doesn't return in cases no `InvocationExpressionSyntax` are found and the transform is never run.
However since you add the `.Collect()` a empty array is passed to `RegisterSourceOutput`.
Maybe I'm wrong and in cases no results are returned from the predicate `RegisterSourceOutput` isn'r run - but I couldn't replicate.

Comment: @schwartz thanks for looking into it. I also created a github issue here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/61162 and people seems to have similar problems. Hopefully the roslyn team can figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate for RegisterSourceOutput will not be called if there are no InvocationExpressions.  If you want a blank output file, you could add a predicate and transform for CompilationUnitSyntax. That will allow you to generate the blank file when no methods are found.